# cucumber tags dynamically set when triggering jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

how can I set cucumber --tags while triggering jenkins job using jenkins API, i.e. "SERVER_URL + CFH_JOB + BUILD_WITH_PARAMS + "/TEST_ENV=" + env_url + "/BROWSER_TYPE=" + browser"

in my RunnerTest it looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/html/", "json:target/cucumber.json"},
    features = "src/test/resource",
    tags = {"@Application"}

    )
```

I would like to dynamically change the tag parameter and control which test suite to run.

Thanks
Ronen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594007/get-cucumberoptions-tag-property-using-system-getproperty/30819258

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar use case in my project. My java project uses Maven, so I can call an "Invoke top-level Maven targets" as a Pre Steps.
In this case, you have to pass an additional String paramater in your Jenkins job :
SERVER_URL + CFH_JOB + "buildWithParameters?TEST_ENV=" + env_url + "&BROWSER_TYPE=" + browser + "&TAGS=" + tags

Where tags could be : tags= "@Application,~@ignore"

Then, in your jenkins job, in the Invoke top-level Maven targets, Goals, you can pass :
-Dcucumber.options="--tags "$TAGS

This option will overwrite the tags defined in your runner.