# How to pass @CucumberOptions as parameters from Jenkin's job

Tags: jenkins, junit, cucumber-jvm

I have `5 Junit Test Classes` to execute `test cases` in parallel and I have hardcoded `cucumber --tags` in `@CucumberOptions`. Now I want to pass `cucumber --tags` as parameters from `jenkin's` job.

Ex:

```
-- tags = {@Students,@Courses,@Faculties,@Admin,@Visitors}
```

in a way that each `tag` is assigned to any `Junit runner` randomly when job is invoked.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jenkins allows you to pass Maven parameters in the job itself. Based on that you can use the format in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594007/get-cucumberoptions-tag-property-using-system-getproperty/30819258#30819258)

Comment: @Reimeus: Thanks for your reply.. I tried this solution before posting my question here.. but it did not work. all the tags are run in single test class.where as(if we consider your suggestion) I want tag(@other) to run  in test class A & tag(@now) to run in test class B and I want these tags should be passed from Jenkins in a way that each test class should pick one tag when jenkin's job invokes.